# Need suggestion for creating attached layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

I want to create soccer lineup like attached image. user can remove any time in 2nd, 3rd and 4th row of item and add up to max 5 player. Which one will better layout for this design tableview layout, or different recyclerview or gridview or something else?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. Virtually RecyclerView is a default choice for lists and grids nowadays.